# Pass NULL value from OIC mapper to ERP Rest Adapter

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-fusion-apps, oracle-integration-cloud

I am still new to developing integrations in OIC. I am using the Oracle ERP Adapter in OIC to update some Invoice staging tables in ERP Cloud. I accidently populated a field with a value that I didn't intend to, and now I am trying to re-update to set it back so it shows as `NULL` in the staging table. I've tried passing a blank value in the mapper as `''` and `""` and the API must be ignoring that as the table value remains with the (incorrect) value still populated.

I've also tried using "xsi:nil=true" in the mapper as you see below, but it just sends the literal value in quotes to the table. Removing the quotes results in a validation error in OIC.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Im Mysql you can just be like variable = NULL.
Pasting a BLANK value is an EMPTY and is technically still a String,
and THUS it is NOT NOTHING .. which you WANT it to be Nothing (NULL)

Comment: I tried that, but with just using the value of `NULL` I still get an error in the mapper - Mapping for Target is not valid. Click here for more details

Comment: I'm not sure about oracle, but it could be possible to have the database setup to NOT allow NULL, or REQUIRE it to be an INTEGER ... so in that case you just convert a NULL to 0, but I'm not sure that is the case here .. but you are on the right track, it might just be the method.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options. You can follow either one.
You also can check the code view, if you want to know how both the options work.

1. Delete the target node

[image: OIC Mapper - Delete target node]

2. xsi:nil=true

In your screenshot, you are sending a string "xsi:nil=true" as a value for "**Vendor Number**". Instead, you should map value "true" to the **nil** attribute. I have circled the attribute in red in your screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First check, if the "***Vendor Number***" is anywhere used as *foreign-key* and the column "***Vendor Number***" is nullable.

- If the answer is "NO", than you should be able to pass NULL.
  → Oracle distinguishes between empty strings and NULL.
- If the answer is "YES", than you have do reset all associated foreign keys at first and opt. update "***Vendor Number***" to be nullabel.